# How to fix " Python Return Method not returning the integer in a concatenated string

Tags: python, concatenation, python-2.x

When the code is run it outputs, but not as required, it returns blank on all the percentages

```
def income():
    num= raw_input("Enter your Income: ")
    print "Your income is: %d " % int(num)
    return num
income= income()

def bills_expenses():
    bills_kitty=0
    bills_kitty=(income*(55/100))
    return  ("Your bills kitty should have: ", bills_kitty)

def long_term_savings():
    long_term_savings_kitty=(10/100)*income
    return "Your long term kitty should have: ",  long_term_savings_kitty

def play_and_leisure():
    play_and_leisure_kitty=(10/100)*income
    return "Your play and leisure kitty should have: " , play_and_leisure_kitty


def education_personal_growth():
    education_personal_growth_kitty=(10/100)*income
    return "Your personal growth  kitty should have: ", education_personal_growth_kitty


def pay_myself_Financial_fredom():
    pay_myself_Financial_fredom_kitty=(10/100)*income
    return "Your pay yourself kitty should have: ", pay_myself_Financial_fredom_kitty

def give_back_to_the_community():
    give_back_to_the_community_kitty=(5/100)*income
    return "Your giving back kitty should have: " , give_back_to_the_community_kitty



bills=bills_expenses()
long_term = long_term_savings()
play=play_and_leisure()
education=education_personal_growth()
mine=pay_myself_Financial_fredom()
give=give_back_to_the_community()


print bills
print long_term
print play
print education
print mine
print give
```

The expected results are that each method when called should output the percentages.
but this is what am getting.

```
Enter your Income: 200
Your income is: 200
('Your bills kitty should have: ', '')
('Your long term kitty should have: ', '')
('Your play and leisure kitty should have: ', '')
('Your personal growth  kitty should have: ', '')
('Your pay yourself kitty should have: ', '')
('Your giving back kitty should have: ', '')
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are facing is twofold.

The type of your input with raw_input is string, you get no error because

```
print "tata" * 2     # tatatata
```

is a valid string notation - you multiply by 0 all the time, so you get empty strings: `''`.

Secondly you need to adjust the division to return floats.

Fixed code:

```
def get_income(): # See Prunes post
    num = float(raw_input("Enter your Income: "))
    print "Your income is: %d " % int(num)
    return num

income= get_income()

print(type(income))

def bills_expenses():
    bills_kitty=0
    bills_kitty=(income*(55/100.0))
    return  ("Your bills kitty should have: ", bills_kitty)

def long_term_savings():
    long_term_savings_kitty=(10/100.0)*income
    return "Your long term kitty should have: ",  long_term_savings_kitty

def play_and_leisure():
    play_and_leisure_kitty=(10/100.0)*income
    return "Your play and leisure kitty should have: " , play_and_leisure_kitty

def education_personal_growth():
    education_personal_growth_kitty=(10/100.0)*income
    return "Your personal growth  kitty should have: ", education_personal_growth_kitty

def pay_myself_Financial_fredom():
    pay_myself_Financial_fredom_kitty=(10/100.0)*income
    return "Your pay yourself kitty should have: ", pay_myself_Financial_fredom_kitty

def give_back_to_the_community():
    give_back_to_the_community_kitty=(5/100.0)*income
    return "Your giving back kitty should have: " , give_back_to_the_community_kitty

bills=bills_expenses()
long_term = long_term_savings()
play=play_and_leisure()
education=education_personal_growth()
mine=pay_myself_Financial_fredom()
give=give_back_to_the_community()


print bills
print long_term
print play
print education
print mine
print give
```

Output:

```
Enter your Income: Your income is: 200 
<type 'float'>
('Your bills kitty should have: ', 110.00000000000001)
('Your long term kitty should have: ', 20.0)
('Your play and leisure kitty should have: ', 20.0)
('Your personal growth  kitty should have: ', 20.0)
('Your pay yourself kitty should have: ', 20.0)
('Your giving back kitty should have: ', 10.0)
```

You will get float-inaccuracies - see  [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) - you can use `round(3.2222,2)` to round to 2 decimal digits.

Answer (score 2):

The code is quite clear: `income` returns a string.  Your "arithmetic" on the string returns an empty string.  Convert it to `int` before returning.  Also, do not overload the variable `income`:

```
def get_income():
    num = int(raw_input("Enter your Income: "))
    print "Your income is: %d " % num
    return num

income = get_income()
```

Answer (score 0):

raw_input is returning a string here, not an integer, so you'll have to cast the income variable to an int, and error handle when it cannot be cast.

Since income is a string, . The subtle error here is in the multiplication. In python2, integer division returns the rounded-down integer. This means 55/100 will give back 0, not 0.55. You need float division, so 55.0//100 will give you .55.

Essentially, you're multiplying your income input (a string) by 0. String multiplication by a value x in python repeats the string x times. So, you're getting a blank string here.

Answer (score 0):

Just return the income as int

```
return int(num)
```